# Recursively remove elements from a list given a condition in OCaml?

Tags: ocaml

I want to remove elements from a list that are greater than a number n.

```
let rec remove_greater lst n =
```

I'm very new to OCaml and I'm not sure how to approach this problem nor how to delete elements from the list. Any advice/tips are appreciated :) Thanks

Comment: `List.filter (fun elt -> elt > n) lst`

Answer (score 2):

OCaml lists are immutable, so you can't delete elements from them. What you really want to do is to make a new list with just the elements you wanted to keep.

The natural way to solve this would be with a recursive function that looks at the two cases for lists: empty list and non-empty list. A non-empty list has a head and a tail.

It will be much easier for SO readers to help if you have some specific code to talk about. We don't want to write your code for you :-)

Answer (score 0):

List.filter will do what you want.  As has been mentioned, in ocaml lists are immutable.  List.filter will construct a new list containing only elements which meet the predicate passed to that function.